# VSCode unable to find Flutter SDK

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, dart

flutter newbie here, was setting up yesterday, managed to get it functional with Android studio.

Running flutter doctor in terminal showed everything checks out. But running flutter doctor in VSCode, keeps giving me an SDK not found message.

- I have the SDK downloaded, it's been added to path
- Flutter plugin has been added to VSCode along with dart
- Terminal flutter doctor shows green check next to VSCode
- I tried several times to set flutter folder as SDK using find SDK to no avail

Any input in this would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is a common problem that will occur when you don't configure the VScode well.

Since you already have the flutter SDK downloaded, and the VSCode installed, open the VScode and press `Ctrl + Shift + P` on your keyboard. You'll get a processing dialog box searching for the SDK like this:

[image: Locating flutter SDK on VSCode]

Click on `locate sdk`

Then browse and select the flutter SDK path.

Also, make sure to install flutter and Dart plugin for VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

It'is very important where you install flutter sdk to have administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

Put your flutter sdk in C main drive and add c:/flutter/bin to user variable path in system environment setting and then restart your ide. your error will fix